# Разбор предложения, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, синтаксический-разбор, вставная-конструкция

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать следующее предложение.

**Катались на салазках с горы, устроенной на дворе Хряпова, но подул сильный ветер, детей позвали в комнаты старика, — и они с ним сидели на теплой лежанке — Ваня с одной стороны, Люба с другой.**

Не могу разобраться, предложение ***и они с ним сидели на теплой лежанке*** является вставной конструкцией или сложносочинённым предложением?
На вставную конструкцию не похоже (если его убрать, то выйдет "детей позвали в комнаты старика, Ваня с одной стороны, Люба с другой").
Может, это сложносочинённое предложение, вторая часть которого заключает неожиданный вывод противопоставления (отсюда и тире)? Но тогда откуда перед ним взялась запятая?

И ещё: предложение ***Ваня с одной стороны, Люба с другой*** — это бессоюзное предложение или вставная конструкция? Если вставная конструкция, то почему она выделяется тире в конце предложения, а не скобками?
Спасибо. Совсем запутался...

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Катались на салазках с горы, устроенной на дворе Хряпова, но (2) подул сильный ветер, (3) детей позвали в комнаты старика,– (4) и они с ним сидели на теплой лежанке – (5) Ваня (сидел) с одной стороны, (6) Люба (сидела) с другой.**

1) Сложное предложение с сочинительной и бессоюзной связью.  Союз НО обозначает сочинительную связь между 1 и  2, 3 и 4, при этом между предложениями  2 и 3 бессоюзная связь, а между 2, 3 и 4 – союзная связь (союз И).

2) Между 4 и 5,6 бессоюзная связь, обозначенная тире (раскрытие содержания).

3) Предложения 5 и 6 неполные (пропущено сказуемое).

4) Сложное предложение дополнительно делится на два смысловых блока, между ними, кроме запятой, ставится тире, обозначающее увеличенную паузу.

Comment: А про четвёртый пунк где можно подробней прочитать?

Comment: Здесь нет одного определенного правила. В принципе автор может просто поставить интонационное тире, обозначив паузу. В нашем случае это одно тире (запятая уже есть), в других случаях ставится единый знак - запятая и тире.  Лопатин считает его устаревающим, Розенталь упоминает про смысловые блоки.  Получается такой информационный микс, из которого следует, что если знак поставлен,то не стоит ему удивляться. Ссылки на эту тему укажу позже.

Comment: РАН: http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg114.php, Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять запятая и тире как единый знак препинания. Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, когда каждый знак стоит на собственном основании. Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp1353. Иногда сложносочинённое предложение распадается на две смысловые части, между которыми ставится тире.

Comment: Большое спасибо.